# Upload image in Django for specific user

Tags: python-3.x, django, postgresql

I am trying to upload pic for specific user but nothing happened when i select image and upload it . it not store in db and not even in media folder

setting.py

```
   MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
   MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

View.py

```
def uploadPic(request):
 if request.method == 'POST' and 'SESSION_KEY' in request.session:
     form = Profile(
         user_id=request.session['SESSION_KEY'],
         profile_pic=ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
     )
     form.save()
     return redirect('home')
 else:
     form = ProfileForm()
 return render(request, 'upload.html', {
     'form': form
 })
```

Model.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   profile_pic = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='image/')
```

Form.py

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model = ProfileModel
       fields = ['profile_pic']
```

Template

```
 {% extends 'home.html'%}
 {% block content %}

  {%if user.is_authenticated%}
    <form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
       {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>

  {% endif %}

 {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly in your form you set `model = ProfileModel` but your model is `Profile` correct that:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['profile_pic']
```

Next in your view in case of a POST request your view is completely wrong. You try to make an instance of Profile and call it form and save it. This is likely failing. Also I assume you write `'SESSION_KEY' in request.session` in an attempt to check if the user is logged in, instead use `request.user.is_authenticated` or in fact disallow anonymous users from accessing your views by using the `login_required` decorator. Change it like so:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def uploadPic(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = ProfileForm()
    return render(request, 'upload.html', {'form': form})
```

**Note**: The indentation of my answer is 4 spaces which is different from your indentation. It is best to indent by 4 spaces for readability. Check about indentation in [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) which is the Style Guide for Python Code.

Comment: @usmanimtiaz what do you use this for `'SESSION_KEY' in request.session`? Also have you added the media urls to urlpatterns?

Comment: yes i added urls : urlpatterns = [ path('upload', views.uploadPic, name='upload'),] if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Comment: Thank u so much for helping now my pic has shown in media folder and also in db :) after removing session_key line from condition

Comment: just last thing how can i display my pic

Comment: If you want to save multiple images for one user your current implementation is fine. Otherwise if you want to store only one you should have a one to one field instead of a foreign key. Anyway with your current implementation if you want to display the first image: `{% with profile=request.user.profile_set.first %}<img src="{{ profile.profile_pic.url }}">{% endwith %}`

Comment: i am using this function just for uploading and display profile pic

Comment: but when i change profile pic it still show first pic which i upload